# What is popular provider service to use for call smart contract or send transaction on Ethereum Sepolia TestNet

Tags: blockchain, web3js

I deployed simple experience smart contract using Remix IDE and MetaMask.

my simple experimental contract address in Sepolia.

(0x56926CB88108126d30AF0844FDBB12522A34D01a) https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x56926cb88108126d30af0844fdbb12522a34d01a

Now, I want to call that smart contract in web3.js

I googled and found Alchemy Provider, but this Provider only supports transaction transfer to the mainnet. (I haven't actually used it, just document says.) https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-sendprivatetransaction

So, my question is.

**What is popular provider service to use for call smart contract or send transaction on Ethereum Sepolia TestNet.**

I wrote that on the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use remix,
[image]

Choose environment is injected Provider and switch Sepolia network on metamask, choose contract that you have deployed in Contract and paste the address at "At address" and you can call and send transaction

Comment: The answer was nearby me, thanks.